# summary row with gtsummary

Tags: gtsummary, gt

I am trying to create a table of events with gtsummary and I would like to obtain a final row counting the events of the previous rows. add_overall() and add_n() do add the total but in a column, counting the same event across groups but not the overall events.

I created this example.

```
x1 <- sample(c("No", "Yes"), 30, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.85, 0.15))
x2 <- sample(c("No", "Yes"), 30, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.9, 0.1))
x3 <- sample(c("No", "Yes"), 30, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.75, 0.25))
y <- sample(c("A", "B"), 30, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.5, 0.5))

df <- data.frame(as_factor(x1), as_factor(x2), as_factor(x3), as_factor(y))
colnames(df) <-c("event_1", "event_2", "event_3", "group")

tbl_summary(df, by=group,  statistic = all_categorical() ~ "{n}")
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O40JY.jpg)

I tried using summary_rows() function from gt package after converting the table to a gt object but there is an error  when summarising because these variables are factors.

Any other ideas?

Comment: You can use this function from gtsummary. https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tbl_cross.html

Comment: Thank you for your rapid response @DanielD.Sjoberg. As far as I know tbl_cross only allows for a single column from the data as a row and displays both categories. What I have are columns of events (event_1, event_2, etc... as yes/no variables), and only want to present the number of each events and the number of overall events (as in adverse events tables in RCT)

Comment: Oh, I see, I misread the example table. One solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding a new variable to your data frame that is the row sum of each of the events. Then you can display that variable's sum in the summary table. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
#> #Uighur
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  data.frame(
    event_1 = sample(c(FALSE, TRUE), 30, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.85, 0.15)),
    event_2 = sample(c(FALSE, TRUE), 30, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.9, 0.1)),
    event_3 = sample(c(FALSE, TRUE), 30, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.75, 0.25)),
    group = sample(c("A", "B"), 30, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.5, 0.5))
  ) |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(Total = sum(event_1, event_2, event_3))

tbl_summary(
  df, 
  by = group,  
  type = Total ~ "continuous",
  statistic = 
    list(all_categorical() ~ "{n}",
         all_continuous() ~ "{sum}")
) |> 
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on stack overflow
```

| **Characteristic** | **A**, N = 16 | **B**, N = 14 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| event_1 | 4 | 4 |
| event_2 | 1 | 2 |
| event_3 | 7 | 6 |
| Total | 12 | 12 |

<sup>Created on 2023-01-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much (great package gtsummary). That works! I had some trouble summing over factors. If variables are factors the code

```
 mutate(Total = sum(event_1=="Yes", event_2=="Yes", event_3=="Yes"))
```

does it.